# How to use output for one function as parameter for another

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

I am trying to work on one file, and I have two functions a and b.

suppose a was:

```
def A(num1,num2):
    num3 = num1 + num2

def B(num3,num4):
    num5 = num3*num4
```

how would I use the output from A(num3) and use it in B?

Comment: You can try `def B(num3=A(num1,num2),num4):` where you need to put `return num3` in your `A` function

Comment: Add a return statement so  that your function returns the result of the computation

Answer (score 4):

First, you need your functions to *return* values. Currently `A()` is just computing the value `num1 + num2` and not doing anything with it. If you want it to pass back the answer, you have to add a return statement at the end of it:

```
def A(num1,num2):
    num3 = num1 + num2
    return num3
```

Next, if you want to pass the result of that function into function `B`, you'd do this:

```
...
some_var = B(A(num1, num2), num4)
...
```

See, it works the same as calling a function anywhere else, except it's inside the parentheses and in the same place as you might otherwise put a variable.

Comment: You need to assign the return value to `num3` inside `B` because `num3` is local to `A` right now

Comment: @Bazingaa As defined right now, that assignment happens when `B` is called, because its first argument is named `num3`.

Answer (score 2):

1) RETURN the output of function A.

```
def A(num1,num2):
    num3 = num1+num2
    return num3
```

2) When you call function A, store the result in another variable.

```
result = A(12,14)
```

**The variable result will now contain the value of (num1+num2). We will pass this as an argument to function B.**

3) When calling function B, in place of num3, pass the value stored in 'result'. The second argument can be any number.

```
B(result,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

what your looking for is the "return"
basically it allows your function to give an output that you could use later.

for example:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2

def a(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def b(num3,num4):
    return num3*num4

num3 = a(num1, num2)
num5 = b(num3, num2)
```

in general this is pretty basic and not very good code practice because i don't know what your trying to solve. further information might help writing a better use of code for your problem :)
i wouldn't actually use this code other than to demonstrate the return in this situation 
just so you know, while defining a function doesn't actually do anything until you call it so the fact you gave it the same name does not bind the actual values in any way.

i would recommend you read more about python basics regardless. good luck!